# Is there a way to make the nodes share a common group of modules and then add specific modules to them?

Tags: module, nodes, puppet

Is there a way to make the nodes share a common group of modules and then add specific modules to them?

In my configuration, all nodes have a base configuration, but some of them have specific modules.

In these common modules, all the configuration is exactly the same, no matter what module, so the "easy" path would be simply add them to each node in the main manifest.

Hardcoded would be something like this:

```
node default{
    include module 1
    include module 2
    include module 3
    include module 4
}

node 'www.example1.com'{
    include module 1
    include module 2
    include module 3
    include module 4

    include module 5
    include module 6
}

node 'www.example2.com'{
    include module 1
    include module 2
    include module 3
    include module 4

    include module 7
    include module 8
}
[...]
```

As you can see, it is very repetitive and inefficient, mostly beacause I will add several nodes and modules.

Is there a way to accomplishing this using only Puppet?

Comment: You want roles and profiles: http://garylarizza.com/blog/2014/02/17/puppet-workflow-part-2/ https://docs.puppet.com/pe/latest/puppet_assign_configurations.html#assigning-configuration-data-with-role-and-profile-modules https://rnelson0.com/2014/07/14/intro-to-roles-and-profiles-with-puppet-and-hiera/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to make the nodes share a common group of modules and then add specific modules to them?

Yes, there are several ways.  Prior to Puppet 4 there were more, but I'll stick to mechanisms whose shelf life is not known to be limited.

There are three general possibilities:

1. Instead of declaring each specific module for each node, define classes that aggregate common groups of modules, and declare *those* on your nodes.
2. Externalize the classes that are to be applied to your nodes, and load them via an Hiera array-merge lookup.  You then get all the benefits of Hiera for sharing data.  There is a standard function that makes this very easy: `hiera_include()`.
3. Employ an ENC to [help] classify your nodes.  Use whatever mechanism you want in the ENC's source language to group classes and to assign groups to nodes.

The Roles & Profiles pattern that @MattSchuchard references in his comment is a popular and powerful approach of type (1), and you should definitely look into it.  It would be overkill for your example code, however; I might instead rewrite the example like this (a simpler type-1 approach):

```
class default_modules {
    include module 1
    include module 2
    include module 3
    include module 4
}

node default{
    include default_modules
}

node 'www.example1.com'{
    include default_modules

    include module 5
    include module 6
}

node 'www.example2.com'{
    include default_modules

    include module 7
    include module 8
}
[...]
```

Comment: You can also combine all three. I personally use roles and profiles with a Hiera ENC that leverages Facter and a CMDB. Everything stays clean and organized, and everything works automatically with little effort.

Comment: I starting to use roles and profiles. I think it will fit. Thank you.